# what is the use of .map function, and what does that _. mean in scala

Tags: scala

I am new in scala language and following the tutorial from the book play for scala here is the code

```
package models
case class Product(ean: Long, name: String, description: String)
object Product {
var products = Set(
Product(5010255079763L, "Paperclips Large",
"Large Plain Pack of 1000"),
Product(5018206244666L, "Giant Paperclips",
"Giant Plain 51mm 100 pack"),
Product(5018306332812L, "Paperclip Giant Plain",
"Giant Plain Pack of 10000"),
Product(5018306312913L, "No Tear Paper Clip",
"No Tear Extra Large Pack of 1000"),
Product(5018206244611L, "Zebra Paperclips",
"Zebra Length 28mm Assorted 150 Pack")
)
def findAll = this.products.toList.sortBy(_.ean)
def findByEan(ean: Long) = this.products.find(_.ean == ean)
def save(product: Product) = {
findByEan(product.ean).map( oldProduct =>
this.products = this.products - oldProduct + product
).getOrElse(
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product not found")
)
}
}
```

above is the full code I have some problem in understanding some line of code please help me

```
def findByEan(ean: Long) = this.products.find(_.ean == ean)
```

what is _. why its used in this line _.ean

what does fine method returns

```
findByEan(product.ean).map( oldProduct =>this.products = this.products - oldProduct + product
)
```

what is the use of .map built in method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is a higher-order function that applies a transformation the content of a generic container.

In this case the container is an `Option`, returned by the `findbyEan`. `Option` can be a `Some(x)`, in which case it contains `x`, or a `None`, in which case it doesn't contain a value.

`map` only applies the transformation in the first case, i.e. if it's `None` it will remain `None`.

---

`_` is a shorthand for lambdas arguments.

`find(_.ean == ean)` directly translates to `find(p => p.ean == ean)` (well, modulo the variable name, which I called `p`)

Comment: def findAll = this.products.toList.sortBy(_.ean)

Comment: why we are using _.ean ??

Comment: because `sortBy` takes a lambda specifying the sorting key. In this case you sort by `ean`